# Solving PDE by using laplace transformation

Tags: partial-differential-equations, laplace-transform

Partial Differential Equation is:
$$\frac{∂u}{∂t} = \frac{∂^2u}{∂x^2}$$

Where $t>0$, and $0<x<1$.

With the boundary conditions:

$$u(0,t)=1$$
$$u(1,t) = 1$$

and the initial conditions:

$$u(x,0) = 1+\sin{(πx)}$$

I'm trying to solve this by using Laplace transform but I couldn't.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You haven't even bothered to ask a question. Good effort.

[Here](http://www.math.ttu.edu/~gilliam/ttu/s10/m3351_s10/c15_laplace_trans_pdes.pdf) is a list of examples for your problem. Example 3 is something very similar to what you are trying to do. If I was you - Be able to understand all three examples before trying the one you've posted, otherwise you won't get it. Good Luck! Post your attempts if you get stuck and we can help.

Comment: Now it looks better

Comment: Have you ever done any similar examples? What have you attempted thus far? If I defined $\mathcal{L}$ as the Laplace operator, would you know what $\mathcal{L(\frac{\partial u}{\partial t})}$ was?

Comment: Actually I don't have any similar examples and Also I looked some "advanced engineering math" lecture book but I couldn't find

Comment: Thank you so much @Rumplestillskin

Comment: @M.dogan All G. If it's what you're looking for then kindly accept the answer so people know you're all set! Example 3 is almost identical to your problem so you should be sweet.